# Principal Components vs Principal Directions

Tags: probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, regression

I'm trying to do statistical downscaling of some climate data and there is a module of principal component analysis by regression method required.

I am confused with the different terms here. What is the difference between principal components and principal directions?

Comment: Perhaps none.  I've never heard the term "principal directions" and if I came across it I would surmise that it means the directions in which the principal components point.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I didn't want to assume it without validation. I found it in a technical paper regarding statistical downscaling using regression and SVM.